Calculated field based on record count and dimension
I want to create a calculation where if the "Record Count" > 1 the field displays "Multiple records found" but otherwise returns the Dimension field "project_name".
This is the attempted formula:
if (Record Count>1, "Multiple records found", project_name)

However this calculation isn't allowed because it "mixes metrics and dimensions".
Is there a way to solve this or some work-around?
